# Battery Statistics Viewer crashes every time

Tags: 2.2-froyo, force-close, battery-life

I have a DroidX with Android 2.2

I went into the Battery Usage settings

Settings > Battery Manager

See a fual cell looking battery image that says `Touch for usage statistics`, so I was like awesome let me nerd out and look at my battery usage statistics.

Then when I touch the image I get an error `The application Settings (process com.android.settings) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.` and the only thing I can do is Force Close.

Anyone have any insight into this issue?

I tried using aLogCat to find the error log after I got it, but it won't pause so I can read anything :-/ Where can I report this bug to Google, if there isn't a fix out there already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a software update coming out to fix this in the "near future". The actual release date for this update was not specified...
[Here is the FAQ on the Motorola website...](https://motorola-global-en-usa.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/58009/~/droid-x---forced-close-error-using-battery-manager)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a common bug with Droid X users and there doesn't currently seem to be a fix.  See this relevant [thread here](http://androidforums.com/droid-x-support-troubleshooting/154450-2-2-battery-manager-force-close.html).

Comment: I actually got it to work for a few minutes after reading that thread, but then it went back to not functioning. :( Do you know how to report bugs for the Android OS?

Comment: There appears to be a fix coming out soon https://motorola-global-en-usa.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/58009/~/droid-x---forced-close-error-using-battery-manager

Comment: Most Android issues are listed/added here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list but this seems to be a manufacturer problem, not stock Android

Comment: Yeah that's what I found out, I didn't realize the manufacturers basically customize Android so much, I thought it was stock Android OS... Silly me :)